# Replica set sharding. Can second data centre do failover?

Tags: mongodb, replication, sharding, failover

We have 3 shards, replicated over 3 boxes each (9 boxes in total). 2 replicas are at our main hosting provider (site A) and we have a third replica (set to secondary only) on another hosting provider (site B). If site A fails, (how) can we automatically take requests from site B?

We have configured site B's replica to secondary-only as advised in http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication/ I know you can do rs.SlaveOk() on these boxes and take requests but this would only do the local shard, which is a third of the database.

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot automatically failover when the majority of the replica set is not available.

Losing site A means you've lost 2/3rds of your replica nodes.  In order to have site B nodes accept reads and writes, you have to reconfigure the replica set.  You can either remove the nodes at site A from the configuration or add arbiters to restore "majority".

Note that you will not have any redundancy running this way, so I would recommend that rather than trying to come up automatically or as quickly as possible, in case of major loss of servers that you take the time and spin up new servers that will provide redundancy of your new configuration.

If surviving the loss of a data center is a requirement for your application, the recommended configuration would be to have the same number of nodes in DC1 and DC2 and then an arbiter in a third location (so that whichever data center failed, you could ensure that majority of the replica set is still present and can elect a new primary).

Comment: Thanks for this. I was thinking about the case where site A is down temporarily. So I could manually configure site B to forget about site A, but then if site A returns, I could manually configure it back again?

Comment: that's certainly an option.